# How to repair Raid 0 Via Terminal

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, disk-utility, raid

I have 2 @ 4TB drives in an 8tb Raid 0 stripe enclosure that has become corrupted.  I have tried to repair the volume via, disk utility, terminal and single user mode with no luck. All 3rd party software seem to only offer recovering as an option.  I am hoping there is still some way I can repair this drive.  Please let me know.

The message I receive is as follows:

```
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume
Checking extents overflow file
Checking catalog file
Incorrect number of thread records
Checking multi-linked files
Checking catalog hierarchy
Invalid volume directory count
(It should be 423 instead of 420)
Invalid volume file count
(It should be 14859 instead of 11142)
Checking extended attributes file
Checking volume bitmap
Checking volume information
The volume EU8TB could not be repaired after 3 attempts
File system check exit code is 8
Restoring the original state found as unmounted
Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed
Underlying error: 8: Exec format error
```

I took a screen shot of orphaned files being fixed under single user mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First - take a backup of your file system. Even though it is already corrupted, it is possible to further corrupt it by trying to fix it. Make sure you have a copy before this.

Then I would suggest simply trying multiple times to check and fix the file system in single-user mode. It sounds counterintuitive, but really you sometimes need to do this multiple times to clear all errors.

You would run a check like this:

```
fsck -fy
```

Note that even though you're "repairing" the file system, it is really just fixing data structures to be internally consistent. You might (and probably will) loose data and files in the process.

As you have a RAID-0 drive, there's no redundancy in the RAID that can help you rebuild the drives while keeping all your data intact. If the data on the drive is important enough for you that you won't be happy if you loose it, then you shouldn't run RAID-0 - but rather a RAID-level with redundancy. And always create backups!

Comment: Thank you?   The raid stripe shows up as disk4.  So would I run fsck -fy /dev/disk4 ? also what is the difference between /sbin/fsck and fsck without it?

Comment: Yes, that’s the way to specify the disk you want. There’s no difference with or without sbin. If your PATH allows it, it is just a shorthand to write it without.

Comment: i tried fsck -fy /dev/disk4

Comment: I received the following message: fsck usage: fsck [ -dnypq] [-l number]

Comment: thats beyond my scope of understanding

Comment: Also after running a command in single user and it finishes.. the next command I input doesn't work. It seems to stop working until I restart

Comment: Just drop the f from the command so it is: fsck -y /dev/disk4

Comment: Note that the "y" means that it will assume you've said yes to any alterations it might want to make to the file system. You can go without "-y" and manually type y to say yes to modifications. However, you might have to do that many, many times.

Comment: What do you mean the next command doesn't work? - How doesn't it work? ... It is definitely not so that you can only enter one command, so you're doing something wrong.

Comment: yes I am most likely doing something wrong :) What I mean is.. that single user mode stops working. When I type in the next prompt, nothing happens.  I end up having to restart..

Comment: And what did you type before? - And what is displayed on the screen?

Comment: For example, I type a task like fsck_hfs -fy and it goes through the process.  after its finished.. I type another fsck_hfs -r for instance.. and nothing happens.  I wait and try again.. still nothing. seems to stop working altogether